# Sharepoint Online Developer Tutorial

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Are You know any good Shareoiunt Online 365 tutorial ? Please share with me link for this tutorial or tutorials.

Comment: Hello and tutorials for what? Administration, User work, new features? Developer for spfx, CSOM, REST api? Just browse Youtube, Google for what you are looking for.

Comment: And there isn't any tutorial for all this methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is list of documentations:

- **https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/**
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps
- https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/how-to-start-using-powershell-with-sharepoint

Youtube channels:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Pt5cnU4MpU&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OV-RPXQ3Lco845qoEy7VJoc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7vLIrm2XKY&list=PLR9nK3mnD-OXvSWvS2zglCzz4iplhVrKq
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLO35ME9aPM&list=PLaIJswamN5lSSYPatSGSG5IC_gZXpBNdv
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq3k0-i2_Fs&list=PLFKlnjWl05IzFbALIeJ-nm4IMp2LlSAC9

I hope this helps!